# Firebase Security Rules restrict access to sub collections

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is my Database-Structure:

users (collection) -> user-docs (uid) -> wishlists (collection) -> wishlist-docs -> wünsche -> wünsche-docs

`users` should be `readable` for everyone, even unauthorized users.
Everything else should be readable/writable **for authorized users only**.

This is what I tried:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow write: if request.auth != null;
}
match /{users} {
    allow read;
}
match /{users}/documents/{allSubcollections=**} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null
}
}
}
```

However this is not working because there is something messed up with `read`. I can not read anything. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

This is how I want to access `users`:

```
//MARK: check username
static func checkUsername(field: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let collectionRef = db.collection(Keys.users)
    
    collectionRef.whereField(Keys.username, isEqualTo: field).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting document: \(err)")
        } else if (snapshot?.isEmpty)! {
            completion(false)
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                if document.data()[Keys.username] != nil {
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should also work if the user is not authorized. Everything else should be restricted to authorized users only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `{users}` to refer to your collection name, that is incorrect, you need to simply use it without the brackets since those are used as wildcards in your rules, eg. you can use `/users/{userId}` to match the `userId` in the rules.

Also I would not recommend using a rule for all collections at the beggining of your rules, as it's a bit error prone. That being said, the following rules should work in your case:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read;
            allow write: if request.auth != null;
        }
        match /users/{userId}/wishlists/{restOfPath=**} {
            allow read,write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Try it out and let me know if it's still not working. Also, check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=6&t=2s) for Firebase Rules, there is a lot of useful information there.

Comment: thanks for your help but this is not working. I can not `read` users if not authorized

Comment: try the edited answer, removing the whole of the generic rule and applying it directly in users.

Comment: try adding the `/{userID}` after `/users`, this indicates that you are applying the rule to every `user` document, I forgot to add that. I don't believe that the problem is in your code, but the firebase rules themselves. Try this out and let me know if it works.

Comment: alright, so the user part is working but now the 2nd rule is failing

Comment: what is `documents` in the 2nd rule? maybe thats the problem

Comment: Great, try same thing, replace the `/documents` by `/{userId}`, this should fix it. let me know and I will update the answer.